# Camera goes dodgy on game build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My demo works well in the editor. However, upon game build the camera follows the player differently. It appears to have a delay like it's following the animation colliders etc. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Camera script

```
{
public GameObject player;
public Vector3 cameraOffset;

void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Jacko");
    cameraOffset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = player.transform.position + cameraOffset;
}
```

}

Comment: Please show your code/setup to demonstrate how you make the camera follow the player.

Comment: Please see updated question for code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're following you're player in Update method you can instead do it in LateUpdate method.
With LateUpdate you know that this is executed always after the Update method of the player.